# PySpark generating consecutive increasing index for each window

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to generate consecutively increasing index ids for each dataframe window, and the index start point can be customed, say `212` for the following example.

**INPUT:**

```
+---+-------------+
| id|    component|
+---+-------------+
|  a|1047972020224|
|  b|1047972020224|
|  c|1047972020224|
|  d| 670014898176|
|  e| 670014898176|
|  f| 146028888064|
|  g| 146028888064|
+---+-------------+
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
+---+-------------+-----------------------------+
| id|    component|              partition_index|
+---+-------------+-----------------------------+
|  a|1047972020224|                          212|
|  b|1047972020224|                          212|
|  c|1047972020224|                          212|
|  d| 670014898176|                          213|
|  e| 670014898176|                          213|
|  f| 146028888064|                          214|
|  g| 146028888064|                          214|
+---+-------------+-----------------------------+
```

Not sure if `Window.partitionBy('component').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)` can be helpful in this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any obvious partitioning here, so you can use `dense_rank` with an unpartitioned window and add 211 to the result. e.g.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'index', 
    F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy(F.desc('component'))) + 211
)

df2.show()
+---+-------------+-----+
| id|    component|index|
+---+-------------+-----+
|  a|1047972020224|  212|
|  b|1047972020224|  212|
|  c|1047972020224|  212|
|  d| 670014898176|  213|
|  e| 670014898176|  213|
|  f| 146028888064|  214|
|  g| 146028888064|  214|
+---+-------------+-----+
```